# Dependency problems while installing libness3-dev using apt-get

Tags: apt, dependencies

I try to install `libness3-dev` and I always get this error.
Can somebody help me please?

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
 python3
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here ist the full error message:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done nodejs is already the newest version
> (6.15.0-1nodesource1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and
> 0 not upgraded. 5 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/464
> kB of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y perl: warning: Setting
> locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
>   LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",     LANG =
> "en_US.UTF-8"
>     are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE
> to default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set LC_ALL
> to default locale: No such file or directory Setting up python-pip
> (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: 6:
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: pycompile: not found dpkg:
> error processing package python-pip (--configure):  subprocess
> installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
> dpkg: error processing package python-pkg-resources (--configure): 
> package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it
> before attempting configuration dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of python-setuptools:  python-setuptools depends on
> python-pkg-resources (= 33.1.1-1+certbot~xenial+1); however:   Package
> python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up python3
> (3.5.1-3) ... running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5...
> /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/dh-python.rtupdate: 5:
> /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/dh-python.rtupdate: py3clean: not found
> error running python rtupdate hook dh-python dpkg: error processing
> package python3 (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation
> script returned error exit status 4 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of dh-python:  dh-python depends on python3:any (>=
> 3.3.2-2~); however:   Package python3 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
> processing:  python-pip  python-pkg-resources  python-setuptools 
> python3  dh-python E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
> (1)
```

Distribution: 4.4.0-137-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 13:14:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You'll have to scan further up & look at your actual error.  The E: line you've provided is only a summary from the calling routine that is reporting an error in a called routine that listed the error earlier in your report.  We can't see what you've not included (the actual error message is higher in your listing).   Please also provide your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Your distribution is **not** 4.4.0-137 as that's kernel information, likely from `uname -a`.  Two different releases of Ubuntu could be using that kernel so it's not definitive. Can you please also correct the formatting of your post; the lines breaks are wrong. You have non-Ubuntu sources there I suspect (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pkg-resources) so I'd suggest adding `apt-cache policy python-pkg-resources python-setuptools` to your question (*and please copy & paste the error again; if you can't format it correctly, we can help you if it's complete & unaltered*)